# Old partitions undetectable and hard drive shrunk after deleting Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

I installed a dualboot of Ubuntu alongside my Windows 8. I created a 20 GB partition on my 120GB SSD for it during install, and it used some gigs on my 1TB HDD too.

After deleting the ubuntu partitions in diskpart.exe in cmd and then using fix MBR and reinstalling windows to get out of being stuck in GRUB rescue, the SSD still only comes up as being 100 GB and The HDD shows 993 GB.

There is no partitions seen other than the sizes above, and no others are detected on diskpart or diskmanager. The worst part?

when booting Ubuntu from USB it can detect the correct sizes instantly! it also shows that there is some residual boot stuff left over on the HDD from my old windows. i have tried the clean command in windows and formatting in disk utility in ubuntu and they are not seen in windows as the original size still

i appreciate this question may not be native to Ubuntu but neither is it to windows.